# Calculating rotation using moment of inertia

Tags: homework-and-exercises, torque, moment-of-inertia

> I have an object A. I know its theoretical moment of inertia.
>
> I have a string wrapped around object A. I then apply a certain tension to that string, causing the object A to spin for a certain amount of time.
>
> I know: Moment of inertia for A, weight of A, force I am pulling with, tension in string, and other things possibly.
>
> How can find out how long object A spins? I tried Googling all sorts of things, but I can't find anything. I also tried a whole bunch of equations my teacher taught us, but I can't seem to arrive at anything.
>
> Assume that when the string runs out, the object stops spinning

This what I have tried so far:

I know how to calculate torque:

$\tau=r\times\vec{F}$

And also angular momentum:

$\alpha={\tau\over{I}}$

Therefore, I can calculate the angular momentum like so:

$\alpha={r\times\vec{F}\over{I}}$

Where $r$ is the radius and $I$ is the moment of inertia, both of which I know. Then I plug the angular momentum into the distance equation:

$\theta_f=\theta_o+V_ot+{at^2\over{2}}$

I then plugin some data that I have, which says that it revolves 11.5 times if pulled with a force of 2.5 Newtons, and takes 9.65 seconds. However, when I plugged in $\alpha$ for $a$ I didn't get 9.65, I got 1.211.

This is basic freshman physics (massless string, no air resistance, etc.)

## EDIT:

It turns out my initial calculations were all correct; I simply forgot to convert centimeters to meters at some point which threw off the whole answer

Comment: @Wolphram did you delete your answer?

Comment: You might use some energy balance $K_1+U_1=K_2+U_2$

Comment: What is slowing the spinning? You mention no friction, so what is removing energy from the system?